# Can I set GNOME Control Center as default in Ubuntu (Unity) 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, evolution, gnome-control-center, office365

I want to use Online Accounts to connect to my Office 365 online account, but the Unity Control Center does not have a plugin for it. I installed and configured GNOME Control Center, however Evolution does not pick up the mail configuration from there.

Is there a way to make GNOME Control Center the default Control Center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity Control Center is **deeply** integrated into the original Ubuntu operating system with the default desktop environment Unity and that's the reason why it has to be the default Control Center. When you want to have the GNOME Control Center as default, you should consider to install Ubuntu GNOME with the default desktop environment GNOME, it's up to you to decide what is more important for you, using original Ubuntu or using integrated Office 365 account.

Please note that this answers the main question about making GNOME Control Center being default, I can't guarantee that Microsoft Office 365 service integration works properly at all - because when it comes to "Microsoft loves Linux" ... well, I don't wanna say too much here ...

Comment: Thanks thats exactly the information I was looking for. I will most likely try another ubuntu based distro instead